# How to implement jQuery plugin without breaking the css in the original file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a jquery plugin today, and I found it is impossible to apply two css files without overlapping each other. In other words, the new plugin will destroy the original layout. Is there any way to make a plugin running in a dividual environment?

Comment: Presumably you mean that your jQuery plugin is reliant on a CSS file and the directives in that file are messing with the directives in some other file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may rebuild the original css code to clear the overlapping by more strict rules, or, you may want to switch the plugins you are using right now to different.

Another thing you could do is change the source code of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by switching the plugins? Different themes?

Comment: Or simply remaking the plugin?

Comment: Yeah, or changing the source is also a good idea because you get to know what you are exactly putting into your HTML file or page

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid overwriting existing CSS without knowing what it could do. Try to add bit by bit of the CSS code to check which code does affect the original CSS. The bottom CSS will always overwrite top CSS.